# How to align horizontally elements without using Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

Is there a way to align the web components next to each other without using `Flexbox`. I know it an awesome tool but unfortunately it doesn't work with IE 9 or 10. I want the text inside the link to appear right next to the images. JSFiddle shows the working code but with FlexBox, how can I achieve this without using Flexbox?

Code:

```
<display:setProperty name="paging.banner.full" value='<span class="pagelinks"> <a href="{1}"> <img src="../images/integration/FastLeft.jpg"/> </a> <a href="{2}"> <img src="../images/integration/SlowLeft.jpg"/> </a> | Page {5} of {6} | <a href="{3}">  <img src="../images/integration/SlowRight.jpg"/> </a> <a href="{4}"> <img src="../images/integration/FastRight.jpg"/> </a></span>'/>
        <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.first" value='<span class="pagelinks"> <img src="../images/integration/FastLeft.jpg"/> <img src="../images/integration/SlowLeft.jpg"/> | Page {5} of {6} | <a href="{3}"> <img src="../images/integration/SlowRight.jpg"/> </a> <a href="{4}"> <img src="../images/integration/FastRight.jpg"/> </a></span>'/>
        <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.last" value='<span class="pagelinks"> <a href="{1}"> <img src="../images/integration/FastLeft.jpg"/> </a> <a href="{2}"> <img src="../images/integration/SlowLeft.jpg"/> </a> | Page {5} of {6} | <img src="../images/integration/SlowRight.jpg"/> <img src="../images/integration/FastRight.jpg"/> </span>'/>
```

CSS

```
.pagelinks {
float: right;
margin-right: 48%;
color: #828282;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center; 
}

.pagelinks a {
text-decoration: none;
}

.pagelinks img {
 border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.pagelinks img:hover {
 border-radius: 3px;
 border: 1px solid #828282;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ssadat/3h1mytqn/)

Comment: Try float left/right

Comment: Have you understood my question? float left/right will move the component left/right while I want them to be aligned :)

Comment: Did you check your jsfiddle?

Comment: @Dekel, is something wrong with it?

Comment: I am trying to get it without using Flexbox.JSFiddle shows with Flexbox.

Comment: The text in the middle Page 5 of 6 goes a little lower than the images without using FlexBox.

Comment: I understand that flexbox doesn't have the support you need, but you might consider a polyfill. https://github.com/jonathantneal/flexibility  Good luck!!

Comment: I was looking into Flexibility but it requires some additional stuff to be added and just for one section of entire application, to me it makes no sense to use.

Comment: Understand, looks like you found your solution!  Since you have images you can use vertical-align on them to get them vertically centered.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For IE10 and below (maybe till IE7/8),

you have 2 solutions:

#### inline-block

you can use `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align:middle` in `img`, and wrap it all with a `div` using some `width` and `margin:auto` to center it horizontally

```css
div {
  width: 50%;
  /* change the value as you prefer, even in px */
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  /*demo*/
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.pagelinks {
  color: #828282;
}

.pagelinks a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.pagelinks img {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.pagelinks img:hover {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #828282;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="pagelinks"> <a href="{1}"> <img src="../images/integration/FastLeft.jpg"/> </a> <a href="{2}"> <img src="../images/integration/SlowLeft.jpg"/> </a> | Page {5} of {6} | <a href="{3}">  <img src="../images/integration/SlowRight.jpg"/> </a> <a href="{4}"> <img src="../images/integration/FastRight.jpg"/> </a></span>
</div>
```

#### table/table-cell

applying `display:table` to `.page-links`  and `vertical-align:middle` to `img`, and again wrapping it in a `div` to center.

```css
div {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

.pagelinks {
  color: #828282;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  /*demo*/
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.pagelinks a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.pagelinks img {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.pagelinks img:hover {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #828282;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="pagelinks"> <a href="{1}"> <img src="../images/integration/FastLeft.jpg"/> </a> <a href="{2}"> <img src="../images/integration/SlowLeft.jpg"/> </a> | Page {5} of {6} | <a href="{3}">  <img src="../images/integration/SlowRight.jpg"/> </a> <a href="{4}"> <img src="../images/integration/FastRight.jpg"/> </a></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without Flexbox

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<span class="pagelinks"> 
  <a href="{1}"> 
    <img src="../images/integration/FastLeft.jpg"/> 
  </a> 
  <a href="{2}"> 
    <img src="../images/integration/SlowLeft.jpg"/> 
  </a> 
  | Page {5} of {6} | 
  <a href="{3}">  
    <img src="../images/integration/SlowRight.jpg"/> 
  </a> 
  <a href="{4}"> 
    <img src="../images/integration/FastRight.jpg"/> 
  </a>
</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
.pagelinks {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;

}

.pagelinks a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.pagelinks img {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3h1mytqn/1/