# How to align items inside div horizontally without using flex

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms

I want to align items horizontally without using flex. In below example I want label, input and span to be aligned horizontally. Cuurently display:flex which is there is working fine but I want without using flex

```
<div class="input-group" style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
<label style="width: 7rem; display: inline-block;">
<span class="control-label" style="color: rgb(64, 64, 64); font-family: Arial; font-size: 50px!important ;font-size: 15px; line-height: 1.5;">Email:</span>
<span class="mandatory">*</span>
<small class="smallExplain"></small>
</label>
<input class="form-control" type="email" name="emailId" placeholder="Email" required="" style="color: rgb(100, 96, 96); font-family: Arial; margin-bottom: 0px; width: 100%; padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem; line-height: 1.5; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 3px solid rgb(0,0,0); border-radius:0.7rem !important; border-radius: 0.25rem;">
</div>
```

Comment: If it is working with `flexbox`, then why do you want to change? Flexbox is great option

Comment: [Already Answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44209896/how-to-align-horizontally-elements-without-using-flexbox) Hope this helped.

Comment: Actually I will use this html code for other functionality, there flex box is not supporting

Answer (score 0):

you can add `margin-right: auto` and `margin-left: auto` css manualy on your input, and label.
For example:

`style.css`

```
label {
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
}

input {
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
}
```

let me know if its works.

Comment: This will add the rules globally for all of the elements (if there are multiple input fields on the same page will be affected by this.).

Comment: You should instad adding a class to scope the inputs. I suggest a generic class name `.centered`

Comment: OR you could add it to your container div `.input-group label, .input-group.input { margin: 0 auto}`

Answer (score 0):

```
.input-group{ margin: "auto";}
```

Adding margin - auto can center the div without using flexbox.